# Is it possible to bin deploy the IIS7 URL Rewrite Module?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

Can the IIS7 URL Rewrite Module be bin deployed with an ASP.net application?

Or does it need to be explicitly installed on every web server?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS7 Url Rewrite Module is a native code DLL so I suspect it will need to be deployed to each web server using the installer.

Comment: any info on licensing and redeployment as part of an msi? (will read the license of course, perhaps anyone already ran into this before?)

Comment: @yonatan - you should ask that as a separate question. I have no idea to be honest.